# How open fragment from RecyclerView.Adapter<CardAdapter.ViewHolder>

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, android-viewholder

1. TabLayout

   - tab1 (Fragment1)
   - tab2 (Fragment2)
   - tab3 (Fragment3)

     - RecyclerView + CardView (OnClick)

On `CardView` ClickListner open another fragment in tab3. So how to open fragment in tab3.

Error is in `getFragmentManager()`:

```
FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
```

which gives

```
/Adapter/CardAdapter.java Error:cannot find symbol method getSupportFragmentManager()
```

Instead of this, I tried:

```
FragmentTransaction transaction = activity.getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
FragmentTransaction transaction = itemview.getContext().getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
```

But error is not resolve.

Here is my code:

```
 public class CardAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CardAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    List<NatureItem> mItems;
    private int lastPosition = -1;
    Context context;
    TaskFragment main;
    public CardAdapter(Context context,TaskFragment ma)
    {

        this.context=context;
        main=ma;
    }


    public CardAdapter() {
        super();
        mItems = new ArrayList<NatureItem>();
        NatureItem nature = new NatureItem();
        nature.setName("The Paris Attack 2015");
        nature.setDes("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.");
        nature.setThumbnail(R.drawable.news1);
        mItems.add(nature);

           }



    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int position) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.custom_list, viewGroup, false);
        ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(v);

     return viewHolder;
    }

  
     @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {
        NatureItem nature = mItems.get(i);
        viewHolder.tvNature.setText(nature.getName());
        viewHolder.tvDesNature.setText(nature.getDes());
        viewHolder.imgThumbnail.setImageResource(nature.getThumbnail());
      //  setAnimation(viewHolder.card,i);
    }

   
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mItems.size();
    }

    class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        private int lastPosition = -1;
        public ImageView imgThumbnail;
        public TextView tvNature;
        public TextView tvDesNature;
       // Button btnclear,btncancle;
        CardView card;
        Activity activity;
        Context co;
        public ViewHolder(final View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            imgThumbnail = (ImageView)     itemView.findViewById(R.id.img_thumbnail);
            tvNature = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_nature);
            tvDesNature = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_des_nature);
            card = (CardView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.card);



    card.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        
        Toast.makeText(itemView.getContext(), "Clicked Card...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
       
           ShareFragment newFragment = new ShareFragment();
            FragmentTransaction transaction =  getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            transaction.replace(R.id.viewFragments, newFragment);
            transaction.addToBackStack(null);
            transaction.commit();

            }
    });
        
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What `fragment` version do you use? If you use the one from the `support library`, you need to get the `SupportFragmentManager`. Also, if you get an error in `logcat`, post it.

Comment: Instead of using context access your parent activity instance. Then it will allow to access fragmentmanager. Also you need to create interface to call fragment.

Answer (score 51):

Open new fragment as follows in your onclick

```
@Override
public void onClick(View view){
    AppCompatActivity activity = (AppCompatActivity) view.getContext();
    Fragment myFragment = new MyFragment();
    activity.getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container, myFragment).addToBackStack(null).commit();
}
```

Answer (score 18):

When you use `adapter` context then for access fragment manager you need to cast your `context`. So you should use this way.

```
YourParentActivity myActivity = (YourParentActivity)context
```

Now you can access method for fragment manager like ,

```
myActivity.getSupportFragmentManager();
```

But keep in your mind that your `Fragment` should be imported as a `android.support.app.v4.Fragment` otherwise there might be a casting problem.

If you open fragment for particular one tab then you should use `getChildSupportFragmentManager()` instead of `getSupportFragmentManager()`

**Note :** If you want to call `fragment` from `adapter` class then you should make `interface` and pass listener to your button click method and implement your activity with that interface.

**Update :**

Also you can pass `FragmentManager` to your adapter constructor. Like,

```
public FragmentManager f_manager;
public CardAdapter(Context context,TaskFragment ma , FragmentManager f_manager)
{
    this.context = context;
    this.f_manager = f_manager;
    main=ma;
}
```

And after that you can use `this.f_manager` in your adapter class `getView()` method.

Answer (score 8):

If you have used support library fragments or default fragments, be sure to use same of it every every where. And use "getSupportFragmentManager" or "getFragmentManager" carefully.

### Pass context inside constructor.

```
public CardAdapter(Context context) {
        super();
        mItems = new ArrayList<NatureItem>();
        NatureItem nature = new NatureItem();
        nature.setName("The Paris Attack 2015");
        nature.setDes("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.");
        nature.setThumbnail(R.drawable.news1);
        mItems.add(nature);
               }
```

### Inside onClick

```
....Your Code

ShareFragment newFragment = new ShareFragment();
FragmentTransaction transaction = /* Here is the change.*/context.getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    transaction.replace(R.id.viewFragments, newFragment);

...Your Code
```

### Update

```
Inside onClick call mainActivity setFragment method to replace fragment.

((MainActivity) context).setFragment(yourFragment);


public void setFragment(Fragment frag){
FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    transaction.replace(R.id.viewFragments, frag);
}
```

Comment: context not working...i add this **import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;**

Comment: `transaction.replace(R.id.viewFragments, frag);`
 _Wrong 2nd argument type_



**Error:(108, 20) error: no suitable method found for replace(int,android.support.v4.app.Fragment)
method FragmentTransaction.replace(int,android.app.Fragment,String) is not applicable
(actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
method FragmentTransaction.replace(int,android.app.Fragment) is not applicable
(actual argument android.support.v4.app.Fragment cannot be converted to android.app.Fragment by method invocation conversion)**

Comment: Recheck if you have used android.support.v4.app.Fragment....
And imported android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction...
And use getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()....

Comment: Now this error is occurs... **Error : java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.example.MainActivity.setFragment(android.support.v4.app.Fragment)' on a null object reference**

Comment: You are close ! Check if "context" you are passing is not null.Then only use ((YourActivity) context).setFragment(yourFragment);

Answer (score 4):

For moving from one fragment to another(from RecyclerView MyViewHolder class) use this

```
Fragment fragment = new AttendanceFragment();
FragmentManager fragmentManager = ((FragmentActivity) mContext).getSupportFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);
fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

Answer (score 3):

For the ones using Kotlin, assuming the fragment class you want to start is called `MyFragment`, and the container where you will put this fragment has id `fragment_container_view`. Probably you will do this inside the `bind` method inside your view holder.

```kotlin
itemView.setOnClickListener {
    val activity  = it.context as? AppCompatActivity
    activity?.supportFragmentManager?.commit {
        addToBackStack(MyFragment::class.toString())
        setReorderingAllowed(true)
        replace<MyFragment>(R.id.fragment_container_view)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this sniped :

```
ShareFragment newFragment = new ShareFragment();
MainActivity mainActivity = (MainActivity)itemView.getContext()
mainActivity.getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
.replace(R.id.viewFragments, newFragment)
.addToBackStack(null)
.commit();
```

Comment: co.getFragmentManager() not working...still get the error.

Comment: Co should be your context or your mainactivity

Comment: how i define context as an activity..??

Comment: getFragmentManager() does not exist on the itemView's context

Comment: Edited, you just have to cast to your activity