# How to start a fragment from an adapter class Android STUDIO

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-fragments

I want to start a fragment from the adapter class of my Recycler View on a button click. I would like to know how I can do this

Comment: You need to provide some code, what you have tried, where you are stuck, here you do not ask for code, you ask for help.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34310592/how-open-fragment-from-recyclerview-adaptercardadapter-viewholder

Comment: @Prince Ali I really appreciate it. U just saved me a lot time

Comment: Next time, try searching google for your problem and add ```stack overflow``` to your search, it will lead you the proper solutions on this site.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How open fragment from RecyclerView.Adapter<CardAdapter.ViewHolder>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34310592/how-open-fragment-from-recyclerview-adaptercardadapter-viewholder)

Answer (score 0):

you can do just like this in your adapter

```
holder.buttonName.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            YourFragment yourfragmentobject = new YourFragment();
            AppCompatActivity activity = (AppCompatActivity) v.getContext();
            activity.getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragmentContainer, yourfragmentobject).addToBackStack(null).commit();

        }
    });
```